# The apk file and dex file is not getting generated by eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

While running any application from my workspace, the application running fine on emulator(and even on my samsung device).But in bin folder, I'm not getting the dex file and apk.The eclipse is not generating the apk and dex file.I did following process
1. clean project
2. deleting R.java file from gen folder.
3. then running the application

Even I re installed the adt bundle. It's weird problem. I even tried export android application to generate signed apk but while doing this it giving me fatal lint errors like app_name is not translated in "af"(Afrikaans),"am"(Amharic) etc.

Can you help me with this?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this way

you can disable **lint errors** this way:

**Window > Preferences > Android > Lint Error Checking**

You should be able to disable

"Run full error check when exporting app and abort if fatal errors are found".

then try to generate signed apk

Comment: I followed you procedure,the Lint Errors are disabled now. And i can generate the unsigned Apk. But what is the reason eclipse is not creating the dex file and apk file building the application